# Could not step in cpp file when debug Openjdk8 hotspot in mac

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, hotspot

I compiled OpenJDK8 in mac. But When I used gdb to debug a simple java class(just system out), it always showed error that **no source file name init.cpp**.
(Had added breakpoint in init.cpp: 95 line). However, it could step into C file like main.c. So not sure whether i had compiled OpenJDK8 correctly or use the correct version for dependencies.
Checked the libjvm.dylib libjvm.dylib.dSYM exist in LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

[When I debug in Eclipse CDT, it has the same issue]

Using ENV:

```
  mac sierra 10.12.6
  gdb 7.12.1
```

Debug command:

```
  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/openjdk/build/macosx-x86_64-normal-server-fastdebug/hotspot/bsd_amd64_compiler2/fastdebug

  ggdb --args ~/openjdk/build/macosx-x86_64-normal-server-fastdebug/jdk/bin/java Test
```

**Result1 (breakpoint in cpp file):**

```
 (gdb) break init.cpp:95

 No source file named init.cpp.

 Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) y

 Breakpoint 1 (init.cpp:95) pending.

 (gdb) run

 Starting program: ~/openjdk/build/macosx-x86_64-normal-server-fastdebug/jdk/bin/java Test

 [New Thread 0x1403 of process 94443]

 warning: unhandled dyld version (15)

 hello,hotspot

 [Inferior 1 (process 94443) exited normally]
```

**Result2 (breakpoint in c file):**

```
 (gdb) break main.c:125

 Breakpoint 2 at 0x100007912: file ~/openjdk/jdk/src/share/bin/main.c, line 125.

 (gdb) run

 Starting program: ~/openjdk/build/macosx-x86_64-normal-server-fastdebug/jdk/bin/java Test

 [New Thread 0x1603 of process 94446]

 warning: unhandled dyld version (15)

 Thread 2 hit Breakpoint 2, main ()

 at 
 ~/openjdk/jdk/src/share/bin/main.c:125
 125        return JLI_Launch(margc, margv,
```

Comment: It' fine after using lldb. As I was using clang instead of gcc to compile and there seems to be some problems if use gdb. But not know what the reason for.

Comment: GDB does not support Mac OS X dynamic libraries preventing from debugging code inside these libraries.  https://github.com/freedib/lldbmi2

Comment: I succeeded with lldb-mi. Thanks ;)